# Configurar reproductor de video html

Tags: html5, video

Estoy poniendo un reproductor de vídeo en mi sitio web

```
<video controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="archivos/mivideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Lo que necesito es quitar la opción `Imagen en Imagen` y agregar la configuración para la calidad de imagen

He encontrado la forma de quitar la opción `Imagen en Imagen`, solo tuve que agregar el atributo `disablepictureinpicture`

```
<video controls disablepictureinpicture controlsList="nodownload">
    <source src="archivos/mivideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Ahora solo me falta agregar la configuración para la `calidad de imagen`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video), no hay un atributo de la etiqueta `<video>` que haga referencia a lo que buscas. Si, por ejemplo, tienes el video en varias versiones con calidad diferente, puedes usar el ejemplo en la documentación para tener varias versiones disponibles a forma de fallback.

```
<!-- Using multiple sources as fallbacks for a video tag -->
<!-- 'Elephants Dream' by Orange Open Movie Project Studio, licensed under CC-3.0, hosted by archive.org -->
<!-- Poster hosted by Wikimedia -->
<video width="620" controls
  poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Elephants_Dream_s5_both.jpg" >
  <source
    src="https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_1024_512kb.mp4"
    type="video/mp4">
  <source
    src="https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_hd.ogv"
    type="video/ogg">
  <source
    src="https://archive.org/download/ElephantsDream/ed_hd.avi"
    type="video/avi">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```